# Online white-boarding tool for diagrams and software design sessions

Tags: collaboration, whiteboard

I used to work with [Dabbleboard](http://dabbleboard.appappeal.com/) as a white-boarding tool across teams. It was a great tool, but was taken down for some reason.

Is anyone hosting anything like it? I found Dabbleboard really easy to use for diagrams and software design sessions.

I would like to be able to

- share UML diagrams trough an url
- design diagrams workflows and plain doodles
- it would be nice if you could draw rectangles/shapes easily
- be able to type in the rectangles
- connect them with arrows and lines

Can you recommend a tool with similar capabilities?

Comment: Please provide a list of requirements for this software to increase your chances of getting a good answert. Merely stating that it's like Dabbleboard isn't enough. Please read the FAQ on [how to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/6834)

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com), it is what I am using for general purpose diagramming.

It supports:

- drag-and-drop manner of putting shapes
- various shapes
- various diagram types
- various arrow types to connect them
- you can put text on both the arrows and shapes
- you can authenticate with your google profile, and have access to all your documents.
- There is an ability to integrate with google drive (I never used this though)
- ability to export the diagram to PDF or image
- diagrams can be shared trough an url

Some disadvantages:

- the tool is free for *simpler* diagrams, that have less than 60 items on them (counting text, arrows and shapes). If you exceed 60 items in a document/diagram, you will have to make a paid subscription to go on.
- some specific diagrams cannot be drawn easily enough with it. For instance, I've found it not that good for sequence diagrams - they take a lot of components (the 60 limit is quickly reached), and they are a bit cumbersome and time-consuming to create.